# Android phone OS crashes when turning on. Can I recover the phones data?

Tags: lost-phone

I have an non-rooted Moto G5 phone that crashes when getting to the main home screen. I get a message that says process system isn't responding and I get the the options to "close app" or "wait" and then the phone crashes 10 seconds later.

I can get the phone to recovery mode and I tried to wipe the cache but that did not help.

I can get the phone to the fast boot screen. If I connect a USB to the phone I see text that says "Transfer Mode: USB Connected"

Can I use Recovery mode or fastboot mode to get my data off the phone? I'm willing to trash the phone as long as I am able to get the data off the phone.

Comment: What do you mean "the phone crashes 10 seconds later"? Are you saying it actually reboots? Have you tried booting it in Safe Mode as soon as the error message occurs (hold power until the Reboot into Safe Mode options shows up)?

Comment: It actually reboots but is not really usable. The home screen isnt visable and I cant access anything other than settings. All phone features are disabled and it says that it cant find the sim card. The phone resets so quickly that I cant really do anything on the settings screen. I've tried booting into safe mode and it only works 1 out of every 10 tries and even when it works the phone will reset after 10 seconds.

Comment: Honestly, unless the bootloader is already unlocked, it is unlikely you can recovery anything on this device. The best you can do is perform a factory reset and attempt to recover the device, but all content will be lost. I know that isn't the answer you are looking for, but stock recovery isn't going to allow you to pull the information you want.

Comment: the message "close app" is from android system_server, this means your phone is successfully booted. just the gui crashes because of some uid errors. try to connect via MTP

Comment: You can try to backup with this method (not sure about encryption)
https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/how-to-backup-qualcomm-phone-root-t3570178
if this fail you may find a flash tool (Qualcomm SW Downloader, QPST, MSMDownloadTool, RSDLite, Snapdragon Flash Tool) which can flash only system - in this case you can flash a modified system.img where you have adb root enabled. then you can backup from adb regardless system_server is crashing